# Liferay - Verify each node in a cluster

Tags: liferay

In this example, I have two clustered instances of Liferay using bundled Tomcat running, using cluster link and shared documents.

Let's say the name of the public community is fubar and friendy URL used is fubar.lipsum.com.

Let's say the ports listening on each server is 8080.

If I go to both server1:8080 or server2:8080 I will get the default page for Liferay.

How can I test fubar.lipsum.com on each node by using the backend server, so I can verify each server?

If I test it, it just goes to the load balancer, I wish there was a way to append to the backend connection to bring it up.

I can add the friendly URL to my local machines hosts file and this seems to kinda work, but then once something is called in the application, it tries to go out again from the backend server and then uses SSL and then we have problems.

I think I may be able to do port forwarding, but this seems like a basic thing we should be able to do and what I've found so far in the admin docs has not helped.  Using the option to print the server name in the page details isn't an option either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to end up using edits to my local hosts file:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

And then putting in the IP address of each machine and the alias to the URL.  Then test one at a time (comment out an entry).

When you test in the browser, you use URI:port, where port is the tomcat port on the machine.

Also, regarding the https issue, the portal-ext.properties need to be checked to make sure:

web.server.protocol=https

isn't active.

This makes the testing not very easy as it requires a restart to disabled the https and then once again to enable https.

It's easy to take a node out of the front end LB pool, but still is a drag when having to test something on an individual node.